# How to post status in facebook / twitter app from a native app?

Tags: cordova

How to post status in facebook / twitter app  from a native app using the settings of the default facebook / twitter  account on the users device with phonegap ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Phonegap or Phonegap Build? In case of the second one you could use [this](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/257) for the facebook thing. For twitter you could use [this](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms), but it will slow down your app a lot because of the needed jQuery and oAuth integration.